# FFmpeg mp3 file header restore

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, headers

I got mp3 files without headers, `ffmpeg -i` shows:

```
 . . . 
[mp3 @ 003e9700] Header missing
 . . .
```

They sound well, but not in all players. So how can I restore header info or re-pack file without re-encoding mp3 content?

Comment: Not sure, but have you tried `ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -c copy output.mp3`?

Comment: Yes I tried `copy` method but it didn't help..